# d3 resummarise nested object

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

In my code I have taken the liberty of removing duplicated rows from a dataset using a d3.nest() function, output sample attached.

Now that I have unique entries in my JSON array I'd like to perform some calculations on this data set, specifically finding the mean 'cycle time' for each date. In this example the output ideally would look like:

```
[
  {
    "key": "2012-03",
    "values": [
      {
        "mean": 16,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "2012-06",
    "values": [
      {
        "mean": 10,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "2012-07",
    "values": [
      {
        "mean": 8,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried following a few examples online but I seem to be missing something obvious, could someone please help?

```
var summaryTable = [
  {
    "key": "2012-03",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "AAA-1",
        "value": {
          "cycletime": 14
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "AAA-2",
        "value": {
          "cycletime": 18
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "2012-06",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "AAA-3",
        "value": {
          "cycletime": 8
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "AAA-4",
        "value": {
          "cycletime": 12
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "2012-07",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "AAA-5",
        "value": {
          "cycletime": 15
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "AAA-5",
        "value": {
          "cycletime": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "AAA-6",
        "value": {
          "cycletime": 8
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

var d3Table = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d['key']; })
    .rollup(function(d) { 
        return {
                "medianCycleTime": d3.mean(d, d3.values(d['values']['value'])),
        };
    })
    .entries(summaryTable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After careful inspection of your `d3.nest` data I found the function to use in the `rollup`.

The argument d of the `rollup` is an array with all the objects that have that key. You have to index that first otherwise you get the `values()` method of the `Array` class.

```
var d3Table = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d['key']; })
    .rollup(function(d) {
        return { 
            "medianCycleTime": d3.mean(d[0]['values'], d => d.value.cycletime ),
        };
    })
    .entries(summaryTable);
```